# Why doesn't this Google AppEngine Search API query find any results?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-search-api

I'm trying to search indexed documents with this query, and it is turning up 0 results, even though the items exist. Why?

Keyword search on the description field and search by year works. 'sbu' is an atom field.

#### Log

```
INFO: Searching with query:  year:( 2013  )  sbu:(Special Bictums Unit) 
Oct 31, 2013 8:36:17 PM com.mwv.pic.service.SearchService search
INFO: results.size:0

INFO: Searching with query:  year:( 2013  )  sbu:("Special Bictums Unit") 
INFO: results.size:0

INFO: Searching with query:  sbu:("Special Bictums Unit") 
INFO: results.size:0

INFO: Searching with query:  sbu:"Special Bictums Unit" 
INFO: results.size:0

INFO: Searching with query:  year:( 2013  ) 
INFO: results.size:3
```

#### Code

```
    log.info("Searching with query: " + q);
    try {
        Results<ScoredDocument> results = getIndex().search(q);
        log.info("results.size:"+results.getNumberReturned());
```

#### Indexes in Admin Console

[image: Imgur]

#### Reference

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/search/query_strings

#### Indexing values

```
Nov 04, 2013 5:55:44 PM com.mwv.pic.service.SearchService indexStudy
INFO: add field sbu:'Special Bictums Unit'

builder.addField(Field.newBuilder().setName("sbu").setAtom(sbu));
log.info("add field sbu:'"+sbu+"'");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Searching for atom fields with blanks in them currently does not work on the Java dev server; but I believe it works in production, and on the Python dev server.

The recommended query syntax is: [sbu:"Special Bictums Unit"] (without the square brackets).

Comment: Wow you are right! This works in production: `sbu:("Food Service") `. Why would they keep the production server different than dev? Why don't they just use the JARs in WEB-INF/lib?

Comment: @Chole Not sure, I think it's either because they want to protect their secret sauce (Ha! What secrets?) or because the real App Engine calls out to Python, and has various redundant storage and resilience features, which is probably viewed as too heavyweight for a local development environment. Unfortunately this results in incompatibilities like this :(

Comment: I am surprised to see this bug, since it was reported in version 1.7, in August of 2012.  I starred the [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=7962); apparently I'm the 10th person who cares?  I guess Java GAE is not very popular?

Comment: Version 1.9.5 of Java GAE seems to have fixed this problem

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with the platform, but the documentation seems to suggest that brackets are only included around values if you are using `OR` or `AND` to search for multiple values. Try using `year: 2013` instead of `year:( 2013 )`, or `sbu: "Special Bictums Unit"` instead of `sbu:("Special Bictums Unit")`.

Also, there seem to be additional spaces around your search queries. I don't suspect that is a problem, but you can call `trim()` on the string to return a version without these, i.e. `q = q.trim();`.

From the documentation:

> If you are searching for an atom field that contains whitespace or special characters, enclose the value in quotes.

To search for an ampersand, it would seem you would need to enclose it in quotes, e.g. `"&"`. However, you cannot search for just a part of an atom field:

> The only valid relational operator for atom fields is the equality operator. The complete contents of an atom field must match the query value.

If you want to find all fields containing an ampersand somewhere in them, they must be text or HTML fields. Presumably the rule about special characters and quotes applies to these as well.

Comment: I already tried without parenthesis. I added that to the question. I also added the part where it indexes, which shows that there are not any trailing or preceding spaces in the atom value.